# Postfix, Dovecot and catch-all

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I've set up my mail server using [a guide from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-e-mail-server-with-dovecot), followed by [another guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-email-server-with-dovecot-dynamic-maildirs-and-lmtp). So, now if I send mail to `torvin@mydomain`, it works.

Now I'm trying to set up a catch-all address for all undelivered mail. Things I've tried so far:

1) Replaced

```
local_recipient_maps = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-boxes.cf $alias_maps
```

line with this:

```
local_recipient_maps =
luser_relay = torvin
```

The result I see in the logs:

> postfix/lmtp[32692]: D5AD540085: to=, relay=mail.mydomain[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.21,
>   delays=0.17/0.01/0.01/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host
>   mail.mydomain[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 550 5.1.1
>    User doesn't exist:
>   thisisjustatest@mydomain (in reply to RCPT TO command))

2) Instead replaced

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-aliases.cf
```

with

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases pcre:/etc/aliases_pcre proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-aliases.cf
```

And created `/etc/aliases_pcre` with the following content:

```
/.*/    torvin
```

Result is the endless loop of:

> to=, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0,
>   dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail forwarding loop for torvin@mydomain)

3) Instead tried

```
virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/aliases_pcre
```

Now all my mail goes to `torvin`, and never gets delivered to any other existing users in the system.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

This is because `/.*/` also includes `torvin`. I assume your `proxy:pgsql:` has information on this user, but `pcre:/etc/aliases_pcre` is looked before that. In this case, the easiest solution would be to reorder them. Also, a simple `hash:` database line `@example.com torvin@example.com` would do the same as your `/.*/` PCRE approach.

Technical implementation aside, having such a **catch-all on a domain with multiple users is a bad idea**. There would not be ANY actual messages that would need attention. What you'd get is:

- **Spam** for non-existent common addresses like `sales@example.com`. This is the most common.
- **Messages destined to someone else**. Picture someone trying to send confidential information to Jane Smith on `<j.smith@example.com>`, but forgets the dot `<jsmith@example.com>` or mistypes it like `<j.smiht@example.com>`. Normally, the sender would receive a notification that the user doesn't exist, double check the email address and resend the message. With a catch-all, this doesn't happen. Instead, there's this `torvin` guy in an awkward and most likely illegal situation.

Both should be treated with a SMTP *connection-stage rejection*.

Comment: I tried reordering and got the same mail forwarding loop problem. Then I tried `@mydomain torvin@mydomain` and got `postalias: warning: /etc/aliases, line 18: name must be local`. I suspect this syntax is supported in `virtual_alias_maps`, but then I will get the problem #3. Any ideas? Also, thank you for your concern, I understand that my setup is quite unusual and your argument is valid in the general case!

Comment: a) As you already have `proxy:pgsql:` you could edit the SQL query to answer with `torvin` when there's no match in the database. b) If you use `hash:`, remember to `postmap`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! a) I don't think it's a SQL query, [`/etc/postfix/pgsql-aliases.cf`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-email-server-with-dovecot-dynamic-maildirs-and-lmtp#postfix) looks like a config file of some sort, but I have no idea how to find documentation for it. And I don't think I can trick it into returning something in case of a miss... b) Sorry, but I literally have no idea what that means. I read the man page for `postmap` but I don't understand how and if it is applicable in my situation (LMTP etc). postfix is just horrifying...

Comment: a) Don't have overly complicated configuration you don't understand. If your users aren't listed in the database, remove such configuration. If that part was relevant, it's certainly possible to modify the SQL query. b) You have `hash:/etc/aliases`, so you already need to to `postmap /etc/aliases` every time you make a change to that file. The `hash:` database for virtual aliases works the same way.

Comment: a) yes, I want to keep users in the DB, because I don't want to create system users for mailboxes. but what I'm saying is, [`/etc/postfix/pgsql-aliases.cf`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-email-server-with-dovecot-dynamic-maildirs-and-lmtp#postfix) doesn't have any SQL query, so there is no way to modify it. b) I used `newaliases` instead... is that wrong?..

Answer (score 1):

When using Postfix with Dovecot LMTP, the catchall function is not supported natively like Postfix's `luser_relay` or Cryus's `lmtp_catchall_mailbox`.

The acceptable way to implement it is to use Postfix's `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias` .

**If there is only one mailbox:**

```
@example.com    root@example.com
```

**If there are more than one mailbox, list all mailbox in `/etc/postfix/virtual_alias` to alias to itself also:**

```
info@example.com    info@example.com
admin@example.com   admin@example.com
@example.com    root@example.com
```

This method is mentioned in the book "Postfix The Definitive Guide".

### Update

`alias_maps` and `luser_relay` are layers within the Postfix local delivery agent(LDA). Checkout https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mailbox_transport.
aliases > .forward files > mailbox_transport > mailbox_command > home_mailbox > mail_spool_directory > fallback_transport > luser_relay.

You can totally replace the Postfix local delivery agent if you are using lmtp. `local_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp`. And put all your alias in virtual_alias `virtual_alias_maps = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-aliases.cf`

The virtual alias rewrites recipient addresses for all local, all virtual, and all  remote  mail  destinations. https://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html
I think local alias is redundant, and is still here for compatibility only.

`local_recipient_maps` could be ignore because of the smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient rule.

> An address is considered "unknown" when 1) it does not match a
> virtual(5) alias or canonical(5) mapping, and 2) the address is not
> valid for its address class.

A catchall row exist in the virtual_alias mean every address will be accepted.

Comment: After 4 years you solved my problem! Thank you, it worked!

Comment: I tested more and it didn't work completely... I have aliases `alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-aliases.cf` - those stopped working. how do I make them work together?

Comment: lol, you still learning mail server after 4 years!! I wrote this comment for people finding the catchall function like me. Check my updated comment.

Comment: not really learning. I just want to configure it once and forget about it. are you saying I should move my aliases into `virtual_alias` file instead? I also have no idea about what local transport is and whether I need to change anything in it

Comment: Yes. Put all mailbox and alias in the virtual_alias source, no matter it is a file or postgresql. The format of mailbox is alias to itself, `torvin@mydomain torvin@mydomain`. Put the catchall row `@mydomain torvin@mydomain` to your virtual_alias source also. Change `local_transport` to the lmtp path that you are using currently.